# do pre-roll ads appear on embedded youtube videos on iOS?

Tags: ios, youtube, video-streaming, video-encoding

We are contemplating using youtube to store and encode our videos for our iOS app.  If we do so, will the pre-roll ads that appear on youtube via the web also appear on mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, no form of ad appears on the mobile or HTML5 versions of YouTube. Embedded ads only appear in the Flash Player driven version of the page, available in desktop browsers.